# RabbiMQ C# driver Causes System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, rabbitmq

We have an ASP.Net WebAPI 2.0 application that publishes messages to our RabbitMQ Server.  In 99% of the cases, all is well... but randomly the application terminates with a System.AccessViolationException for no apparent reason.

How can I prevent this failure?  Could it be related to our recent upgrade to the 3.6.6 C# driver (it worked fine before the upgrade)?

Things I have already eliminated:

1. A new `IModel` is used for each publish (I know `IModel` is not thread
   safe)
2. A call is made to `CreateConnection` for each call as well (I
   know I could reuse the connection, but we do not currently).  The connection is `AutoClose = true;`
3. The Channel is used in a using block... so it is disposed each time

Here is a sample stack trace of where it explodes:

**Exception Details**

> System.AccessViolationException
>
> Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
>
> at System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods.SafeNetHandlesXPOrLater.GetAddrInfoW(String
>   nodename, String servicename, AddressInfo& hints, SafeFreeAddrInfo&
>   handle) 
>   at System.Net.Dns.TryGetAddrInfo(String name, AddressInfoHints flags, IPHostEntry& hostinfo) 
>   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6) 
>   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress) 
>   at RabbitMQ.Client.TcpClientAdapter.BeginConnect(String host, Int32 port, AsyncCallback requestCallback, Object state) 
>   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.Connect(ITcpClient socket, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Int32 timeout) 
>   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler..ctor(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, Int32 connectionTimeout, Int32
>   readTimeout, Int32 writeTimeout) 
>   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.ProtocolBase.CreateFrameHandler(AmqpTcpEndpoint
>   endpoint, Func'2 socketFactory, Int32 connectionTimeout, Int32
>   readTimeout, Int32 writeTimeout) 
>   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IList'1 endpoints, String clientProvidedName)

And another

> System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods+SafeNetHandlesXPOrLater.GetAddrInfoW(System.String,
>   System.String, System.Net.AddressInfo ByRef,
>   System.Net.SafeFreeAddrInfo ByRef) 
>          System.Net.Dns.TryGetAddrInfo(System.String, System.Net.AddressInfoHints, System.Net.IPHostEntry ByRef) 
>          System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(System.String, Boolean) 
>          System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(System.String) 
>          RabbitMQ.Client.TcpClientAdapter.BeginConnect(System.String, Int32, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object) 
>          RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.Connect(RabbitMQ.Client.ITcpClient,
>   RabbitMQ.Client.AmqpTcpEndpoint, Int32) 
>          RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler..ctor(RabbitMQ.Client.AmqpTcpEndpoint,
>   System.Func'2,
>   Int32, Int32, Int32) 
>          RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.ProtocolBase.CreateFrameHandler(RabbitMQ.Client.AmqpTcpEndpoint,
>   System.Func'2,
>   Int32, Int32, Int32) 
>          RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(System.Collections.Generic.IList'1,
>   System.String)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly why your error is occurring I would need to see some of your code for that, but I use RabbitMQ quite a bit and to publish I use a class like so:

(Changed some parts as they are not relevant for your situation such as encryption, compression etc. But this would be the basic format of it)

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Framing;

namespace Messaging
{
    public class MessageSender : IDisposable
    {
        private const string EXCHANGE_NAME = "MY_EXCHANGE";

        private readonly ConnectionFactory factory;
        private readonly IConnection connection;
        private readonly IModel channel;

        public MessageSender(string address, string username, string password)
        {
            factory = new ConnectionFactory {UserName = username, Password = password, HostName = address};

            connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            channel = connection.CreateModel();

            channel.ExchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "topic");
        }

        public void Send(string payload, string topic)
        {
            var prop = new BasicProperties();
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(payload);

            channel.BasicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, topic.ToUpper(), prop, data);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            try
            {
                channel.Dispose();
                connection.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to let you issue multiple calls or a single one and dispose of the class when you wish. Wrap it with a using statement and your set.

Never had a single problem with this in about 3-4 years of using it, so you might be able to contrast this vs your code to find the differences.

Comment: thank you for your input.  <br/> Our implementation doesn't create a new "Sender" class each time, but we do have the Channel wrapped in a using.<br/> For the record, my implementation has been working for 3 years as well without issue... and just started failing recently. Perhaps it is a bug in the version of the driver that I just upgraded to (3.6.6)<br/>

Comment: What version of RabbitMQ are you running. We discovered several problems with 3.6.4. The major one was heart-beats were causing faults in the client and would break the connection. (fixed in 3.3.6 I believe according to the patch notes) Depending on your error handling this could be it. Only noticed it via Windows Event logs that listed the error as originating from the .NET rabbitmq client with "heartbeats" as the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get a (partial) resolution on this from RabbitMQ users group.

Details here:  [Rabbit MQ Users Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/VJRg_IVNKpU)

Basic idea is that the IConnection object should be shared, as it is heavy to open and close.  Only the IModel should be opened fresh for each thread